# NFA for words which start and end with different letters with $O(\log(| \Sigma |))$ states

Tags: finite-automata

I'm trying to build a NFA for the following language
$ L = \{ \sigma_1 \sigma_2 \sigma _3 \ldots \sigma _n \mid \sigma _1 \neq \sigma _n \}$.
The catch is that for $ \Sigma $ such that $ |\Sigma|=2^k $, the NFA should have $\Theta(k)$ states.

I was thinking of representing the letters in binary but I'm not sure what I should do exactly.

Comment: Try applying Myhill–Nerode theorem.

Answer (score 3):

The original question referred to DFA (and not NFAs). However, no DFA for $L$ with $O(k)$ states exists.

Consider $\Sigma$ as a set of words (i.e., each word consists of a single  character from $\Sigma$).
Given any two distinct words $a,b \in \Sigma$, the word $a$ is a distinguishing extension for $a$ and $b$. I.e., $aa \not\in L$ but $ba \in L$.

This shows that the number of equivalence classes of $L$ w.r.t. the equivalence relation "not having a distinguishing extension" is at least $|\Sigma|$.
By the [Myhill-Nerode theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Myhill%E2%80%93Nerode_theorem), any DFA for $L$ must have at least $|\Sigma|$ states.

---

The idea to build a NFA with $O(k)$ states is as follows:
in addition to an initial state $s$, and to an accepting final state $t$ there are $2k$ states indexed with $1, \dots, 2k$.

Assign a distinct integer $x_a$ from $0$ to $2^k-1$ to each character $a \in \Sigma$ and consider the binary string $b_a$ of length $2k$ obtained by concatenating the binary string of length $k$ representing $x_a$ in binary, with its complement.

For each character $a \in \Sigma$ let $S_a$ be the set of all states $i$ such that the $i$-th least significant bit in $b_a$ is $1$, and define $\overline{S}_a = \{1, \dots, 2k\} \setminus S_a$.

For each $a \in \Sigma$, add the following transitions:

- A transition from $s$ to each state $i \in S_a$.
- A transition from each state $i \in \{1, \dots, 2k\}$ to itself.
- A transition from each state $i \in \overline{S}_a$ to $t$.

Given a word $\sigma_1, \sigma_2, \dots, \sigma_n$ with $\sigma_1 \neq \sigma_n$, let $i$ be an index such that the $i$-th least significant bit of $b_{\sigma_1}$ is $1$  while the  $i$-th least significant bit of $b_{\sigma_n}$ is $0$ (such an index always exists).
Then, $s \to i \to i \to \dots \to i \to t$ is an accepting path in the NFA.

Conversely, any accepting path is of the form $s \to i \to i \to \dots \to i \to t$ for some $i$. This implies that $i \in S_{\sigma_1} \cap S_{\sigma_n}$, i.e., $b_{\sigma_1}$ and $b_{\sigma_n}$ differ (at least) on the $i$-th least significant bit. This shows that $\sigma_1 \neq \sigma_n$.

The number of states of the NFA is $2k+2$.

Here is an example for $\Sigma = \{x,y,z,w\}$. All edges for which no label is shown are actually labelled with $x,y,z,w$.

[image: example]

Comment: Hi, I think you're right. Just updated the question - how about NFA?

Comment: When you say "However, no DFA for $L$ exists.", it could be confusing. You should add "with $O(\log |\Sigma|)$ states".

Comment: @Nathaniel, thanks!

Comment: @steven, thank you!

Comment: @steven, by saying "it's complement" (line 3) - do you mean change each bit in $x_a$ ? for example, if a is 00100, then $b_a$ will be 0010011011 ?

Comment: @Galyoss, exactly.

Comment: @steven, sorry for asking so many questions. I've read your response several times, but I'm really struggling here. can you maybe give a few simple words about how the NFA actually checks for a different bit?

Comment: @Galyoss, the NFA doesn't "check for a different bit". Bits only play a role in the procedure needed to construct the NFA. I added an example.

Comment: @steven, as for the (2k+3)th state you mention above - could you please provide an example of a transition which is not covered by the (2k+2) states of the NFA depicted above? Is it a "garbage-collecting" state out of the accepting state to an additional non-accepting state?

Comment: @DilipKumar, for every character $a \in \Sigma$ the transition from $t$ when reading $a$ goes to the rejecting state $r$ . Moreover, for every $a \in \Sigma$, the transition from $r$ when reading $a$ goes to $r$ itself.

Comment: @HendrikJan, you are right. I'll update the answer.